# Set up root folder of JupyterLab in GCP Notebook Instance for Python module import my own source file from different directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm using a GCP notebook instance (from Vertex AI to be precise), and I'm struggling to import a function in a Python script/module (in a particular folder) onto a notebook (in a different folder).

Therefore, is there any way I could set the root folder of my repo as the repo from which Python modules can be located? In Pycharm, I have the option of setting this root folder as the "Sources Root" and all imports work fine. However, I'm not sure how I can do this on JupyterLab of the notebook instance on GCP.

Answer (score 3):

In the **GCP Jupyter(IPython) Notebook**, there is no option to set a “**source root**” like Pycharm IDE. If you want to set an own path to import Python modules/functions, follow the below solutions:

**Example Project Structure:**

```
/home/jupyter/ (Default root directory)
-src
-tutorial
-hello
   - basic.py (function file)
-source
   - test.ipynb
```

**1. Temporary Solution**

- You can temporarily add the corresponding path of the function file to IPython using “**sys.path.append**”. For example, if “**/home/jupyter/hello**” was missing from your IPython path, you can append it as below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/jupyter/hello')
print(sys.path)
```

- After executing the above code, you should be able to see “**/home/jupyter/hello**” added as a path in “**sys.path**”. For example, If you added a path through sys.path.append in “**test.ipynb**”, the added path only works in test.ipynb. It will not work on any other .ipynb. So, If you want to add a path common to all .ipynb, you should follow the permanent solution.

**2. Permanent Solution**

- A permanent solution could be changing the IPython config options. So, open the terminal on the notebook and do the following steps:

**Step 1**: Go to file -> New -> Terminal and execute the following commands to create and locate an IPython config file. Of course, your IPython profile path will probably be different with the example below:

```
$ ipython profile create 
$ ipython locate 
/home/jupyter/.ipython
```

**Step 2**: To edit the config file, execute the following commands:

```
$ cd /home/jupyter/.ipython 
$ nano profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

**Step 3**: Find the “**#c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines**“, remove the “**#**” to uncomment it. Add the following lines to add your own path to “**sys.path**” and save the changes you've made by pressing Ctrl + O and Enter. To exit nano, type Ctrl + X.

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [ 'import sys; sys.path.append("/home/jupyter/hello")' ]
```

**Step 4**: Finally, close your current Jupyter notebook and go to the Notebooks page on VertexAI. Click the checkbox of the notebook instance which you configured. Stop the instance and start it again to update your configuration. Now, open the Jupyter notebook and test your code.